# Issue iterating records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm sure this is a stupid question, but I've got a todo list app I've built in Rails. There are projects and projects have many tasks. Aside from seeing projects with their tasks, I also wanted to see a simple listing of all of the tasks. The index action in the tasks controller looks like this:

```
def index
    @tasks = Task.all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @tasks }
    end
end
```

And in views/tasks/index.html.erb I simply had this to start:

```
  <%= @tasks.each do |t| %>
    <%= t.title %>,
  <% end %>
```

But when I look at /tasks, I get this:

```
Task 1, Task 2, Task 3
#<Task:0x103225138>#<Task:0x1031ea998>#<Task:0x1031ea858>
```

I can't figure out why the

`#<Task:0x103225138>#<Task:0x1031ea998>#<Task:0x1031ea858>"`

...are appearing or how to keep them from appearing. They appear even if I'm not printing anything other than the loop code. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<% @tasks.each do |t| %>
  <%= t.title %>,
<% end %>
```

Will fix that. The problem is that you are printing with `=` the result of `.each` which returns the array it was called on, in this case `@tasks`. So your code is effectively doing this:

```
<% @tasks.each do |t| %>
  <%= t.title %>,
<% end %>
<%= @tasks %>
```

A side note:

A much nicer way to do this is simply

```
<%= @tasks.map(&:title).join ", " %>
```

Comment: No problem and welcome to Stack Overflow. It's customary here to indicate correct answers by clicking the accept button to the left of the question and/or upvoting.

Comment: Thanks Jakub. I tried but it's telling me I still need to wait 5 minutes before I can accept the answer. Yours is the one as soon as I can.